# Using SignalR with Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, signalr, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to use signalR with Service Fabric provided by Microsoft? I'm trying to connect an UWP app and an angularJS app to my stateless reliable service hosted in an Azure Cluster through signalR/websocket connection. But both are not able to open such a connection. On my local machine everything works fine.

Is there anything special to consider of using signalR/websockets with Service Fabric? Is there any example?

Comment: Why have you created 2 questions which are almost the same? Pick one...

Comment: Have a look at this [Backplane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649027/setup-signalr-and-service-bus-inside-a-azure-service-fabric-service/40525730#40525730). I would be glad if its help.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649027/setup-signalr-and-service-bus-inside-a-azure-service-fabric-service/40525730#40525730). Would be glad if this works for you.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I made a library for using Actor Events to scaleout SignalR. "Best Effort" didn't bother me for the intended usage! There's a demo, docs and source [here](https://github.com/olivergrimes/servicefabric-topicactor-signalr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure the load balancer to the client ip. Then the user will always get to the same node and other users to other nodes. The user to node relationship will be persistent.

Comment: Good point Kevin. Could you provide a bit more information about how exactly can I implement mapping client IP to a service host in LB? (I am very new to Azure)
Also, how would you suggest to handle user IP change?

Comment: This stackoverflow article gave a good example of how to use the load balancer. We tried it and it worked. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818744/signalr-with-service-fabric-stateless-web-api)

Comment: I am getting the below error. Are using siganlr.core or 2.2??? version.Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false. Replica had multiple failures during open on _Node_0. API call: IStatelessServiceInstance.Open(); Error = System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException (-2146232828) Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at

Comment: @kevin I am using ngnix not ngnix plus. Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable cross-domain setting for signalR to call it from other applications.

```
 appBuilder.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {

            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration()
            {
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies  = true
            };

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
```

This code can be found in the readme.txt file we get after installing the Nuget package for the SignalR.
For cross domain feature, you need to install the Cores nuget package also.

After deploying this application, you can see that some calls to signalR fails and Some succeeds. 
By default the instance count in Reliable stateless service is -1. Thus multiple instances will be created for the service.

From signaleR Connection.Start() method three SingalR APIs will be called. 
These calls should happen within the same session in-order to work it properly.
When we call these three API in Service Fabric with multiple instances, the call might be processed in different nodes and thus different sessions which leads to failure in singalR connection.

One solution is to Make the instance count 1 for the stateless service fabric application. I don't think that this is an elegant solution.

Comment: I am getting the below error. Are using siganlr.core or 2.2??? version.Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false. Replica had multiple failures during open on _Node_0. API call: IStatelessServiceInstance.Open(); Error = System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException (-2146232828) Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at

Comment: I think i was using signalr 2.* version.. I believe you are using a Stateless service. Are you getting this error while debugging in the local machine ?

Comment: When I use websockets, I get Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 204. But when I use SSE it works fine.