# SignalR with service fabric: work flawlessly locally, so-so on azure cluster

Tags: signalr, azure-service-fabric

I need some advice for a problem happening randomly.
I built a service fabric app using asp.net core (kestrel server) + signalR server 3.0 rc1 and signalR JS 2.2.0 on the client side.
Everything work flawlessly when I am running the app on my local dev machine with the cluster emulator, but when I move the app on the cluster on azure (party cluster) it works only 20% of the time with no particular difference on the 5 nodes (works and fail equally on all the nodes). 
Anyone have an idea of why this is happening? The thing that comes into my mind is that the cluster in azure is behind a load balancer that distributes the requests equally on the 5 nodes, but why sometime fails and some other works?? I copied the signalR log from the javascript console if that can give a better idea of what is going on. Thank you so much for giving a look.

This is the successful log

`[14:24:18 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'sigrhub'.
[14:24:18 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22sigrhub%22%7D%5D'.
[14:24:18 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
[14:24:18 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://party47790.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:8505/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=CfDJ8O6y2JZ%2FleBLogES7fVXm2gLdJZ%2FpJL5l3%2BHD9%2BPeOnWwGeUQ15wsHOUi%2FD2lvu3Ik%2B1AGHBqBF90loShuhVbAKdSS0oVA2Gr%2F9fF8n0kDCQ%2BHwbjGEJ2VG7Ec%2FTG1ldPiYLBlZMyI9q%2Bm08jmstc6vQfkRo8Cn5rwhMbZXdXj1W&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22sigrhub%22%7D%5D&tid=4'.
[14:24:18 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
[14:24:19 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
[14:24:19 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
[14:24:19 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
[14:24:20 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'broadcastMessage' on hub 'SigrHub'.
[14:24:27 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'broadcastMessage' on hub 'SigrHub'.`

and this the failure log

`[14:42:42 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'sigrhub'.
[14:42:42 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22sigrhub%22%7D%5D'.
[14:42:42 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
[14:42:42 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://party47790.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:8505/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=CfDJ8Mx7bLnzN7NAmuxkHBVB9jPnnWRQPXr7sRt54283Qr7ihhaS%2FXD97yxHXP1jiAtKI4HdWWrACChXbNQJz0dEPl9i2ECgqrIIl0YFYSc0amvylrO9KoFaTgrVemNfKGy%2FwM5dALU7dLz3Kv%2BL%2BBfHKzOX0TbpwMdlqutAOvVBELIQ&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22sigrhub%22%7D%5D&tid=10'.
SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 400, Bad Request
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket closed.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: This browser doesn't support SSE.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport starting.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Binding to iframe's load event.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Forever frame iframe finished loading and is no longer receiving messages.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Error occured when stopping foreverFrame transport. Message = Permission denied.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping forever frame.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: longPolling transport starting.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://party47790.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:8505/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=CfDJ8Mx7bLnzN7NAmuxkHBVB9jPnnWRQPXr7sRt54283Qr7ihhaS%2FXD97yxHXP1jiAtKI4HdWWrACChXbNQJz0dEPl9i2ECgqrIIl0YFYSc0amvylrO9KoFaTgrVemNfKGy%2FwM5dALU7dLz3Kv%2BL%2BBfHKzOX0TbpwMdlqutAOvVBELIQ&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22sigrhub%22%7D%5D'.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: longPolling transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Fallback transports exhausted.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
[14:42:43 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: LongPolling failed to connect.`

Comment: Please Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264351/using-signalr-with-azure-service-fabric/36057204#36057204

Comment: I actually found this one a bit more helpful. It describes how to configure the load balancer, which worked great for us. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818744/signalr-with-service-fabric-stateless-web-api)