# SignalR Webscoket in Azure service fabric

Tags: websocket, signalr, azure-service-fabric

I have implemented a sample signalr service and for UI, I used angular5. I am able to connect to the signalr hub using TransportType.ServerSentEvents but not through websocket. Do I need to make any settings for it to work.
I am getting error - failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 204

Comment: [This question about Azure SF and SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264351/using-signalr-with-azure-service-fabric) mentions some load balancer configuration as well as specific SignalR configuration.  Do those apply to your situation?

Comment: I saw that. But I am using ngnix but not ngnix plus. I see session persisitence settings only in ngnix plus. So I want to see any other solution.